# Multiplication of nonsquare matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Could multiplication of **non-square** matrices result in **square nonsingular** matrix?

It's easy to show for square matrices via determinant. But what to do with non-square ones?

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix}1 &0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed, this can happen: $A_{m\times n} \times B_{n\times m}$ may very well be non-singular (though not necessarily) ***provided*** $m \leq n$, as in the case Daniel Fischer posted in the comments:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 &0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} = (1)$$

*However*, we run into problems when $m>n$. Why?

Comment: Thank you and Daniel. $AB$ is $m\times m$ and due to non-singularity its rank is $=m \leq \min (rankA,rankB)$. Hence $m\leq n$

Comment: Exactly! Nice work!

Comment: @Amzoti: I love it when the OP comes away with more than an answer to the question asked! And on his/her own, too!

Answer (score 1):

The standard inner product between vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be thought of as multiplication of matrices and the result is a scalar which can be thought of as a $1 \times 1$ matrix. A $1 \times 1$ matrix is nonsingular when the entry is non-zero.